# Angularjs - http request cancelled - reports 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm having a problem with making an HTTP request in angular.

The request is taking a long time because it waits on a complex database query. If in the meantime the user clicks a link to a different page (we have a couple different single page apps), the request is getting cancelled (which is fine), but the status reported is 404. Now, the request in question should not fail in the ordinary course of business and so when it does we log it to an error reporting service (a different server). The problem is we are getting errors reported when they aren't errors, just cancelled http requests. Is this an error in angular? Is there a best practice to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean "the status reported is 404?" If the client terminated the connection before they get a response, how did a status get reported at all?

Comment: I mean the http error handler is called, and it's status argument is 404. Yes, I understand you are surprised. I'm surprised. Hence the question. I would have expected no response at all! It seems that angular is canceling the request and then calling my error handler and giving it 404 and then loading the new page.

Comment: So the user navigates away, and before the current page unloads, the error callback fires (presumably because the connection was terminated, and not because the server actually responded with an error status), is that it? I guess you then log it to an error reporting service from within that callback? Have you looked into "interceptors?"

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Angular that was introduced in 1.2.8.  I've reproduced and reported the issue here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6074

Stick with 1.2.7 for now, unless you need something from 1.2.8 and beyond.